# Express API endpoint routes return 404 when deployed to Heroku, work locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Trying to make a simple React + Express site and get it deployed to Heroku is proving to be quite the tricky task. The set ups that work on my local machine are:

1. Method 1: I run `npm start` in the **root** directory, followed by `npm start` in the **client** directory with a proxy in the client's package.json pointing to the server address/port.
2. Method 2: I run `npm run build` in the client directory and only run `npm start` in the root directory. (to test this I removed the if statement that checks for production so it would run in development)

Both of these methods work fine on my local machine, however when I deploy to heroku, I consistently get a 404 error when trying to navigate to /api, my server endpoint. I've seen a bunch of posts on SO about this issue and tried every suggestion I read to no avail.

**Server** index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

// API
const router = require('./router/index');
app.use("/api", router);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))
      
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on ${PORT}`)
})
```

**Server** package.json

```json
{
  "name": "ltb_calculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An application for calculating interest for the Lifestyle Trading Bot on Telegram",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "author": "Sonny Parlin",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "react-fetch-hook": "^1.8.5",
    "react-json-view": "^1.21.3"
  }
}
```

**Client** package.json

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The entire project is on github, [here](https://github.com/sonnyparlin/LifestyleTradingBotStrategy). Judging by the number of questions about this on SO, many people are running into this for many different reasons. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong build pack. I don't remember setting up a buildpack, it may be something that heroku added. Anyway, I removed the react buildpack and added a nodejs buildpack and that seems to have fixed the issue for me. It must have been running the react server instead of the express server.

[image]